# Is there a way to handle WCF server faults in one spot on the client?

Tags: wpf, wcf, exception

Right now I am wrapping all my WCF service calls in the following try/catch block and I am wondering if there is a way to set this in one place and have it apply to all service calls.

```
try
{
    Product test = client.GetProductById(1);
}
catch (TimeoutException ex)
{
    WPFMessageBox.Show("The service operation timed out." + ex.Message);
}
catch (FaultException<CustomFault> ex)
{
    WPFMessageBox.Show("CustomFault:" + ex.ToString());
}
catch (FaultException ex)
{
    WPFMessageBox.Show("Unknown Fault:" + ex.ToString());
}
catch (CommunicationException ex)
{
    WPFMessageBox.Show("There was a communication problem" + ex.Message +
                        ex.StackTrace);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a wrapper method that get the code to execute the service call passed in by a delegate:

```
public T ServiceCallWrapper<T>(Func<T> serviceCallDelegate)
{
    try
    {
        return serviceCallDelegate();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        WPFMessageBox.Show("The service operation timed out." + ex.Message);
    }
    catch (FaultException<CustomFault> ex)
    {
        WPFMessageBox.Show("CustomFault:" + ex.ToString());
    }
    catch (FaultException ex)
    {
        WPFMessageBox.Show("Unknown Fault:" + ex.ToString());
    }
    catch (CommunicationException ex)
    {
        WPFMessageBox.Show("There was a communication problem" + ex.Message +
                            ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Then you can call the wrapper for example with an anonymous method like this:

```
Product test = ServiceCallWrapper<Product>(() => client.GetProductById(1));
```

Comment: Thanks, that is nice and simple.

Comment: Jan, how would this wrapper look for methods that accept one or more parameters but don't return a value?  (e.g. Are void.)  (Ex: internal static void LockoutUser(string userID, int timeInSeconds))

Comment: @FarrEver, exchange Func<T> with Action in the method ServiceCallWrapper: `public void ServiceCallWrapper(Action serviceCallDelegate)`

Answer (score 1):

You could do that through AoP and IoC.

Here I have written how:
http://pablocastilla.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/aop-and-ioc-in-wcf-4-0-with-enterprise-library-5-and-appfabric-part-1/

There is a code example.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that works to catch server Faults on the client. Could you explain a bit?

Comment: You would catch them as AoP style. Through Enterprise Library  configuration you configure the client in order to process the exceptions in different ways.

Comment: Thank you, I would like to investigate it a little further some day but for now I don't have the time so accepted Jan's answer